# Function printf() to print backspace problem

Tags: c, printf

There are two programs and they get different results, but I don't understand why.
Here is the first:

```
int main()
{
    printf("12345");
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\b\b");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is: `123`.
Then the second:

```
int main()
{
    printf("12345");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\b\b");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

but the result is: `12345`.

Why does the sleep call make the second result different when I expect a "123" result?
The code was running in the CLion.
and My OS is macOS, if it matters.

Comment: Can't reproduce :( https://wandbox.org/permlink/MD5eQDJ9m78fa6Y2

Comment: @hellow pretty normal you cannot reproduce, the behaviour of printinf `\b` depends entirely on the terminal used.

Comment: note that my os is macOS

Comment: when it comes to outputting `\n` (newline), `\r` (carriage return) and `\b` (backspace) to a terminal, keep in mind how a [mechanical type writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter) performs those actions. It could not erase characters, since they were already printed on paper. The behavior of terminals is modeled after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the Terminal, `'\b'` might "erase" a character or only move the cursor to the left. To have a foolproof solution, use:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("12345");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\b\b  \b\b");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code first displays "12345" and then displays "123". Without the `sleep`, the "12345" is displayed for too little time to be visible. With the `sleep`, you can see the "12345" for about a second before the "4" and "5" are erased.

Comment: but the "4" and "5" were not erased

Comment: That is not what OP described.

Comment: @cyberdriver please edit your question and make clear what _exactly_  your get and what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

With the original code (called `bs97`, compiled from `bs97.c`), and with my command line prompt `Osiris JL:`, I get the output:

```
Osiris JL: bs97
123Osiris JL:
```

Note that the new prompt has overwritten the `45`.  You can see that if you add `putchar('\n');` after the second `fflush()`.  (I added `void` to `int main(void)` to avoid compilation warnings (errors) with my default compilation options.)

```
Osiris JL: make bs97 && bs97
    gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes bs97.c -o bs97
12345
Osiris JL:
```

This time, the `4` and the `5` are still visible.

*Simply using backspace does not erase the content that was previously there;* it positions the write position on screen back one place, that's all.  If you want to erase what was there, you need to output `printf("\b \b\b \b")` to go back, output a space, and go back again — repeated twice.  Or you could use `printf("\b\b  ")`, but that would leave the write position after the two spaces; or you could use `printf("\b\b  \b\b")` to leave the write position after the `3`.  And there are other variations on this theme.

With the second program with the sleep, I get similar behaviour, except that the `12345` is on display while the program sleeps.

I'm testing on a Mac running macOS 10.14 Mojave, using a home-built GCC 8.2.0 or the `clang` compiler from XCode 10.0.

Comment: I would argue that we could produce quite different results every time OS and terminal is changed. Making concrete examples kind of useless. Nonetheless this is a nice in depth answer.

Comment: @KamiKaze: That's part of why I stated the O/S I'm using.  However, there's also a core functionality to most Unix-like (POSIX-ish) systems that means this code will normally behave the same, across versions of a single system and across different systems.  I'd not expect to see much difference on Linux instead of macOS, for example.  I don't see an option in the macOS `stty` to make backspace erase what was there before.  I expect there is a terminal type where that's what happens, but I don't think such terminals are in common use.