# Can't dynamically allocate a string

Tags: c, string, dynamic

I tried to dynamically allocate a string using a function I named `ALLO`, but when I execute I get an error, which is my function `ALLO` can't get the string using `getc`, it gets skipped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void ALLO(char *str){
    char  c=0;
  int i = 0, j = 1;

  str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

  printf("Enter String : ");

  while (c != '\n') {
    // read the input from keyboard standard input
    c = getc(stdin);

    // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
    str = (char*)realloc(str, j * sizeof(char));

    // store read character by making pointer point to c
    str[i] = c;

    i++;
    j++;
  }

  str[i] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

  printf("\nThe entered string is : %s", str);

  free(str); // important step the pointer declared must be made free
}
int main(){
    char *NomAF;
    int NAF;
    printf("Entrer le nombre des ateliers : ");
    scanf("%d",&NAF);
    ALLO(NomAF);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *semantics* are wrong.

You ask the user for the names of the athletes, and then you scan it into an integer. You should ask for the number of athletes first. Then, *after that*, you allocate memory to accommodate each name.

```
int num_names;
scanf("%d", &num_names);
```

After you know the number of names, you then allocate a buffer *for each* name, separately.

```
char **names;
names = malloc(num_names * sizeof(char **));
for(int i = 0; i < num_names; i++)
    ALLOC(&names[i]);
```

Also, you shouldn't be using `scanf` for user input. Use `fgets` instead, which is a little better.

Then, you also should be using a `pointer to pointers` to get those strings.

A little modified version of your code (which you should review and fix, as needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ALLO(char **str){
    /* use INT for getc() return */
    int  c=0, i = 0;

    /* you are gettting 1 byte of memory */
    *str = malloc(sizeof **str);

    /* should use fprintf(stderr...) or fflush(stdout) to guarantee 
     * the sentence will be seen by user
     */
    printf("Enter String : ");

    while (c != '\n') {
        // read the input from keyboard standard input
        c = getc(stdin);

        // re-allocate (resize) memory for character read to be stored
        /* i = 0 in the first run,
         *
         * and you have 1 byte alloced in the first run.
         *
         * so you get 1 byte for actual getc() return
         * 1 byte for next character + NULL byte
         *
         * NOTE: you are STORING the NULL byte in your string. You only
         * check for it AFTER you do the assignment, so your strings
         * contain a newline before the NULL byte.
         */
        *str = (char*)realloc(*str, (i + 2) * sizeof **str);

        // store read character by making pointer point to c
        (*str)[i] = c;

        // you can use only 'i' for this...
        i++;
        /* @i
         * 
         * Using only 'i' requires that you understand what @i is doing
         * during execution. @i will keep the current buffer position,
         * and you know you need one more position for the next
         * character and one more for the NULL byte. 
         *
         * Therefore, in your realloc statemente, you need @(i + 2)
         */
    }

    (*str)[i] = '\0'; // at the end append null character to mark end of string

    printf("\nThe entered string is : %s", *str);

    // if you free here, you can't get the string at @main for printing.
    // free is the last step
    //free(str); // important step the pointer declared must be made free
}

int main(){
    char **NomAF;
    int NAF, i;
    char buf[100];

    printf("Number of athlets : ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    NAF = atoi(buf);

    NomAF = malloc(NAF * sizeof *NomAF);
    // check malloc errors

    // get names
    for(i = 0; i < NAF; i++) {
        ALLO(&NomAF[i]);
        printf("New name: %s\n", NomAF[i]);
    }

    // print names, then free() then
    for(i = 0; i < NAF; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", NomAF[i]);
        free(NomAF[i]);
    }

    // free the base pointer
    free(NomAF);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me first, I have one more question, why did you use the buf variable ? couldn't you just store it in NAF directly ?

Comment: @AbdessalamSemlali No, `NAF` is an integer, `buf` is an array of characters. `buf` is a _buffer_ for intermediate storage of user input.

Comment: Woing type in `NomAF = malloc(NAF * sizeof(char**));`.  Use `NomAF = malloc(NAF * sizeof *NomAF);` and avoid that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
 while((c=getchar()!='\n')&&c!=EOF);
```

before getc it skips white space.

Because after this `scanf("%d",&NAF);` take you are giving input `5(+enter)` this goes `5'\n'` 5  is got by scanf and '\n' is in buffer and this new line is got by your `getc`.

and change this `str[i] = '\0';` to `str[i-1] = '\0';`, it replaces the newline with NULL and you allocated memory for `i` characters only.

You can return the string by `return str;` and change function return type as `char*` or if don't want that take a parameter that allocated by malloc.

See this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ALLO(char *str)
{
char  c=0;
int i = 0;

printf("Enter String : ");

while (c != '\n')
{
    while((c=getchar()!='\n')&&c!=EOF);
    c = getc(stdin);
    str = (char*)realloc(str, (i+1) * sizeof(char));
    if(!str) exit(1);
    str[i] = c;
    i++;
}
str[i-1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *NomAF;
    int NAF;
    NomAF=malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(!NomAF) exit(1);
    printf("Entrer le nombre des ateliers : ");
    scanf("%d",&NAF);
    ALLO(NomAF);
    printf(NomAF);
    free(NomAF);
    return 0 ;
}
```

output:

```
Entrer le nombre des ateliers : 5
Enter String : a
s
d
f
g
     ----->newline to stop the loop
asdfg
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.205 s
Press any key to continue.
```

> I entered it as a string not character by character, its not practical to ask the user the enter letter by letter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

char * inputword(char **);

int main()
{
    char *word;

    printf("Enter Word:");
    word=inputword(NULL);
    printf("Word Entered:%s",word);
    free(word);

    printf("\nEnter Word 2:");
    inputword(&word);
    printf("Word Entered:%s",word);
    free(word);
    return 0 ;
}

char *inputword(char **word)
{
    char *str=NULL,ch,*memerr="Memory Error";
    int i=0,flag=1;

    do
    {
    str=realloc(str,((i+1)*sizeof(char)));
    if(!str)
    {
        printf(memerr);
        exit(1);
    }
    ch = getch();
    switch(ch)
    {
      case 13:
         str[i] = '\0';
         putc('\n',stdout);
         flag=0;
         break;
      case '\b':
         if(i>0) i--;
         str[i--]='\0';
         printf("\b \b");
         break;
      default:
         str[i] = ch;
         putc(ch,stdout);
    }
    i++;
    }while(flag);

    if(word!=NULL)
        *word=str;

    return str;
}
```

output:

```
Enter Word:Hai, How are You?(1 String)
Word Entered:Hai, How are You?(1 String)
Enter Word 2:Hai, How are You?(2 string)
Word Entered:Hai, How are You?(2 string)
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 58.883 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: @Abdessalam Semlali     how did you give the input ?,make sure that you are giving a newline to stop the loop.

Comment: I entered it as a string not character by character, its not practical to ask the user the enter letter by letter

Comment: @AbdessalamSemlali     if you no want  to enter letter by letter use getch

Comment: And see this  (my answer)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60690795/c-programming-issues-with-printing-string-with-backspace-characters-stored/60691048?noredirect=1#comment107379757_60691048

Comment: You may get an idea

Comment: But its not dynamic

Comment: @Abdessalam Semlali    see updated answer, you can do something like that.